# Camera not recognized on Raspberry Pi 3 B

Tags: camera, config.txt

I've tried connecting a camera to my Raspberry Pi and I've enabled it on `raspi-config` but `vcgencmd get_camera` still shows `supported=0` `detected=0`. Also, in my `boot/config.txt`, `start_x=1` is not even commented nor enabled upon enabling camera interface. Another thing to note is my Raspberry Pi constantly shows a low voltage warning but I am unsure whether this is related in any way. What might be the issue?

Comment: Are you on buster on bullseye version of the OS? Anything of note in the output of `dmesg`? `constantly shows a low voltage warning` use a better power supply ... and finally, which raspberry pi are you using?

Comment: oops, sorry, didn't read the title very well :p ... so it's a 3B

Comment: what does v4l2-ctl -V show

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments, I have rectified the issue. The issue was with the bullseye version of the os. I used a buster version and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

1. [Check first if the camera is supported](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_Webcams)
2. Try a powered USB hub to plug in the camera / maybe it isnt getting enough power

Then you can install this tool to test out the camera `sudo apt-get install luvcview`